# is there a way to make it so I dont have to confirm my logout when I try to use remote desktop?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, user-accounts, group-policy

I have 2 accounts on my desktop pc because I dont want a password on my main account so it logs in faster. Well I like to remote desktop into my computer to watch movies on my tablet so I had to make a new account with a password since rdp doesnt let you connect to accounts with no password.

Well any time I want to sign into the account via rdp, I have to go over to my desktop and click confirm so it logs out and into the other user.

When I want to sign back into my computer I have to get my tablet and click confirm so itll log me out of my rdp account.

Is there any way to make it so it just automatically logs out out instead of having to confirm it?

Windows 10

Comment: There is most definitely not a restriction that prevents using RDP without a password as I use it that way on one of my systems.  Do note however that I would never allow outside connections to a passwordless account, which would be very risky.

Comment: Maybe its just the app then but when I tried to connect to my passwordless account it wouldnt let me and said I cant use an account with no password